# UUID vs Long for Id in Hibernate Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a simple hibernate entity:

```
@Entity
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "Technology")
public class Technology {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue()
    @Column
    private UUID id;

    private String name;
}
```

I am using `saveAll` method from spring repositories to import list of technologies. Before the import, I am deleting all existing technologies like this

```
// clear repo before saving all new points
techRadarRepository.deleteAll();
techRadarRepository.saveAll(technologies);
```

I am getting the following exception while trying to do the 2nd import (i.e. with table with existing records)

```
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; statement executed: delete from technology where id=?
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3698) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3958) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
```

The problem disappears if I uses traditional Long as Id field instead of UUID in my entity class. Could someone please explain the behavior and a proper fix to this issue?

Comment: In the database, is the data type for `id` compatible with using a UUID? A Java [`UUID`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) is a 128-bit value.

Comment: I have `jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: update` property, so the DDLs are generated by hibernate based on the entity classes.

Comment: Ok. Have you verified that the data type in the database – whether it was created by hand or auto-generated by hibernate – will work with a 128-bit value?

Comment: I tried to define the DDL myself like this `"ID"  VARCHAR2 (500)   NOT NULL,`. still no luck :(